# WCF services using the same port from different processes?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I know you can create multiple services on the same port within a single process. We have the situation where we are assigned a port to use for all traffic but the architecture doesn't currently support starting all wcf services from a single process.  Obviously, all services have different endpoint addresses.  Is there a way to add multiple services on the same port from different processes?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosting in IIS using WAS allows you to yuse host headers to route to the appropriate service on the same website.

Answer (score 0):

no... each service should listen on it's own port otherwise - who can they tell who should get the call ?
you can consolidate the services to a single one, but I wouldn't recommend it...

Comment: I was hoping that given the entire service URI is unique, there would be a way for the system to route requests through the same port to different processes.